# Extracting data from XML Name Value List with Python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to extract certain data from an XML response.  I am able to get certain tags, but the information I need is within a different format that I haven't had any luck with. I have the following XML stored as a variable `itemspecifics`.  What I need is the value for `Manufacturer Part Number` which is `90105-MV9-003`.  What I don't understand is how to extract this data because the tag name `<name>` repeats.

```
>>> print itemspecifics
<itemspecifics><namevaluelist><name>Brand</name><value>Honda</value>
<source>ItemSpecific</source></namevaluelist><namevaluelist>
<name>Country/Region of Manufacture</name><value>Japan</value>
<source>ItemSpecific</source></namevaluelist><namevaluelist>
<name>Manufacturer Part Name</name><value>BOLT, DISK (8X24) (TSUKIBOSHI)
</value><source>ItemSpecific</source></namevaluelist><namevaluelist>
<name>Manufacturer Part Number</name><value>90105-MV9-003</value>
<source>ItemSpecific</source></namevaluelist><namevaluelist><name>Placement 
on Vehicle</name><value>Rear</value><source>ItemSpecific</source>
</namevaluelist><namevaluelist><name>Retail Price</name>
<value>$20.96</value><source>ItemSpecific</source></namevaluelist>
<namevaluelist><name>Type</name><value>rear rotor bolt set</value>
<source>ItemSpecific</source></namevaluelist></itemspecifics>
>>> 
>>> print(type(itemspecifics))
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

Answer (score 1):

XML is easier to parse with [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

```
itemspec = """<itemspecifics><namevaluelist><name>Brand</name><value>Honda</value>
<source>ItemSpecific</source></namevaluelist><namevaluelist>
<name>Country/Region of Manufacture</name><value>Japan</value>
<source>ItemSpecific</source></namevaluelist><namevaluelist>
<name>Manufacturer Part Name</name><value>BOLT, DISK (8X24) (TSUKIBOSHI)
</value><source>ItemSpecific</source></namevaluelist><namevaluelist>
<name>Manufacturer Part Number</name><value>90105-MV9-003</value>
<source>ItemSpecific</source></namevaluelist><namevaluelist><name>Placement 
on Vehicle</name><value>Rear</value><source>ItemSpecific</source>
</namevaluelist><namevaluelist><name>Retail Price</name>
<value>$20.96</value><source>ItemSpecific</source></namevaluelist>
<namevaluelist><name>Type</name><value>rear rotor bolt set</value>
<source>ItemSpecific</source></namevaluelist></itemspecifics>"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(itemspec)
nvl = tree.findall('namevaluelist')
d = {}
for r in nvl:
    k = r.find('name').text
    v = r.find('value').text
    d[k] = v
assert d == {'Brand': 'Honda', 
            'Country/Region of Manufacture': 'Japan', 
            'Manufacturer Part Name': 'BOLT, DISK (8X24) (TSUKIBOSHI)\n',
            'Manufacturer Part Number': '90105-MV9-003', 
            'Placement \non Vehicle': 'Rear', 
            'Retail Price': '$20.96', 
            'Type': 'rear rotor bolt set'}
```